# T-SQL ORDER BY custom sorting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Having IDs in range (-12 to 700, no 0).

I want to output a table sorted by IDs with IDs 1 to 700 coming first and then from -1 to -12.

Avoiding dealing with unions and splitting the sets by >0 and <0, is there a way to sort it like I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of `CASE` expressions would do this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN YourColumn > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC,
         CASE WHEN YourColumn > 0 THEN YourColumn END ASC,
         YourColumn DESC; --As already inferred it is now less than 0
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b5688bd7b8d8b8fca18d44aa4a81b83)